# How to know whether a file is in making or completed in java?

Tags: java, file

I am calling sqlloader to load data file to data base from java. Log file is generated for that. The log file generation can take long time depending upon the size of the data file.  From separate java call I need to know whether the log file writing is completed or not. If the log file writing is completed then I will show "Load Complete" or else I will say "Load Running." 
But how to know whether the log file is fully completed or still in making?

Comment: Have you checked out the solutions offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750471/how-to-know-whether-a-file-copying-is-in-progress-complete-in-java-1-6)?

Answer (score 0):

You could search for `Elapsed time` in log file. If it is there, it is done. Otherwise still running.

Comment: I tried that. But if the size of the log file is very high and has huge number of lines then it is not an efficient way. It is taking to much time to read the whole file and search for the specific word. Need to try somrthing else.

Comment: oh ok. I have tried the same in Unix script. If possible, write some unix script and try calling it.