# How to monitor file transfer in Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, monitoring, file-transfer

I am writing a utility to check whether a very big file has been completely transferred.

From what I found online, I understand that the best way is to have the sender send a bite-sized file to indicate that a file transfer is complete. For instance, after sending a 10GB video file `bigfile.mov`, the sender then sends a 1KB `bigfile.txt` containing the checksum or something to identify the file; the receiver then polls for `bigfile.txt`.

However, in my case, this approach is not open to me because I have no control of the files being sent to me. Therefore I am resorting to the much more unreliable approach of polling a file a certain number of times in specified intervals, for its file size and last-modified time.

```
public static boolean hasFinished(String sFilename, int polls, int interval) {

    boolean isDone = true;
    File file = new File(sFilename);
    long size = file.length();
    long lastModified = file.lastModified();

    if (file.isFile()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < polls; i++) {

            // sleep a bit
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Checking...");
            if (file.length() != size || file.lastModified() != lastModified) {
                isDone = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return isDone;
}
```

I am writing this utility on Windows, and I test this by copying a very large file from a temp location to where I want it (say `C:\bigfile.mov`). The problem is that, once the file copying begins, it seems that both the file size AND the last-modified time are locked in, so even when I test this method while the file is still being copied, I still get `true` as my result (which is obviously not the case).

How should I change my code in this case?

Comment: Typically, data isn't written to the disk as it's downloaded.

Comment: Are you transferring from 1 server to another or from 1 directory to another?

Comment: @Telthien I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Eventually this utility should check for files coming in from anywhere - it could be an external machine or within the machine itself. For current development and testing purposes I'm simply copying a file from directory A to directory B. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Why don't you copy the file to a temp name, and rename it once the copying is finished? Then, you only see the completed copy. (Depending on how you copy, the target file indeed might have its final size and time stamp before the last byte has been written.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to (re-)set the file attributes of the target file. If that fails, the file is still opened and thus still being created (by the copy process). I think that would be the best solution if you do not want to modify the copy process (or are unable to use the copy-to-temp-then-rename idea for whatever reason).

Comment: @TheBlastOne As mentioned, I don't have any control over what is sent, and how it is sent. Anything that involves something on the sender's end is likely out of my reach, which is why I'm trying my best to work with what I can do on my end.

Comment: Then I´d consider getting the target file´s file attributes, and set them again. If that fails, the file is still in the works. (Of course assuming you have the rights to set the attributes.)

Comment: You can use a separate thread to check whether the file size is increasing. If the file size is not changing after few checks (for example after 3 checked with 30 seconds) delay then you can consider as complete. You can increase the number of check or the time delay to fit your need.

Comment: @JosephSelvaraj That's essentially what I'm doing in my code. The problem is as mentioned in the last paragraph. I can't test if it's working properly because the file size and timestamp don't change even when the file is being copied.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Let me think of any other solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know whether a file copying is 'in progress'/complete in java (1.6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750471/how-to-know-whether-a-file-copying-is-in-progress-complete-in-java-1-6)