# Android: Does it give an Uploadmanager for ftp like the Downloadmanager?

Tags: android, upload, ftp

In Android I have a downloadmanager used like this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));
```

Now I like to know if there is a way to set up an upload progress bar like in the downloadmanager for ftp uploads?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't find it (it looks like there isn't), but you can make your custom progress bar.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871515/progress-bar-in-notification-bar-when-uploading-image) are some answers of how to do it.

Hope it helps.