# HTTP_BAD_REQUEST errors while sending image files using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I have a problem sending images to my server using httpurlconnection. i have read [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) and another [HttpUrlconnection implementation](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection)  but i don't know where am doing it the wrong way since am getting a HTTP_BAD_REQUEST error code(400). what important thing am i missing in my code below?

My response code always return 400 but my link is ok since am able to achieve this using httpclient

```
 link = "my link.com";

 try {
   URL   url = new URL(link);

   connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setUseCaches(false);
   connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

   BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
   FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bytesRead;
   while ((bytesRead =stream.read(buffer ,0 ,buffer.length)) != -1){
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            outputStream.flush();
   }
  outputStream.flush();

  responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Can your server handle Content-Type = image/jpeg? Try to use some console or REST Client to test your request to find out if your request is correct. I think it should be Content-Type multipart/form-data

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work

Comment: @CyberAleks   my server can handle that since am able to send the same file with the same content type using httpclient

Comment: @CyberAleks     what reasons could make my httpurlconnection to fail while httpclient is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is how the image is being added to the output stream.  All of the connection configuration steps look good.

I tried this method recently and it worked well:

https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

It is also good practice to wrap in an AsyncTask.  I have noticed that MultipartEntity is now deprecated, but you can replace with MultipartEntityBuilder.

**update**

To listen to file upload events and update your progressbar, You can override the `writeTo` method of any HttpEntity implementation and count bytes as they get written to the output stream.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/sorry");

   MultipartEntity outentity = new MultipartEntity() {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CoutingOutputStream(outstream));
    }

   };
   outentity.addPart("stuff", new StringBody("Stuff"));
   httppost.setEntity(outentity);

   HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity inentity = rsp.getEntity();
   EntityUtils.consume(inentity);
} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

static class CoutingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    CoutingOutputStream(final OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        System.out.println("Written 1 byte");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        System.out.println("Written " + b.length + " bytes");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        System.out.println("Written " + len + " bytes");
    }

}
```

**update**
If you would like to update a progress bar based on the http progress this link provides a great example

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9854555/5693681)

Comment: i have ended up implementing httpclient though i never wanted. my concern is how can i listen to upload progress? how  can i update my progress bar using this http client?

Comment: Do you want a definite or indefinite progress bar?  If you use onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods in an AsyncTask you can easily start and stop an indefinite progress bar

Comment: i want a definate one and am using `ByteArrayEntity` instance as my entity in my `HttpPut put = new HttpPut(link); `    `put.setEntity(bytearrayEntity)`

Comment: I think this may be what you are after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854555/android-http-upload-progress-for-urlencodedformentity

Comment: men your second link in your last comment worked. please add it to your answer and i will accept it