# Retrofit File Upload with progress bar is not working in android

Tags: android, file-upload, progress-bar, retrofit, percentage

In my application i have used Retrofit for uploading files to server. Now i want to show the percentage of file upload in progress bar. I have found a solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348812/android-retrofit-onprogressupdate-for-showing-progress-notification).

But the progress bar fills quickly for every different sized files. I think this progress is not the actual amount of data uploaded to server. Is there any other solution in Retrofit for this issue..? I have also checked with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100096/is-there-any-way-to-get-upload-progress-correctly-with-httpurlconncetion).

Is it possible in Retrofit..?

Please see my code

this is custom typed file

```
public class CountingTypedFile extends TypedFile {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public CountingTypedFile(String mimeType, File file, ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mimeType, file);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(super.file());
        long total = 0;
        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                total += read;
                out.flush();
                this.listener.transferred(total);
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code part executed in doingbackground of AsyncTask

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(mImgUri);
            File file = new File(AppUtils.getRealPathFromURI(context, myUri));
            totalSize = file.length();
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
                    .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                    .build();
            RetrofitCommonService mRetrofitCommonService = restAdapter.create(RetrofitCommonService.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "File is not null when converting from bitmap");

            TypedFile fileToSend  = new CountingTypedFile("image/png", file, new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {
                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                }
            });

            ImageUploadResponse imageUploadResponse = mRetrofitCommonService.upLoadImage(new AppUtils(context).getPhone(),
                    AppUtils.getDeviceId(context), fileToSend);
```

This is my Retrofit service

```
@Multipart
@POST("/user/asset")
@Headers("Accept:application/json")
ImageUploadResponse upLoadImage(@Header("mobile-number") String mPhone, @Header("uid") String imei,
                                @Part("file") TypedFile mBody);
```

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: am facing the same problem looks like one has to roll out his own Client may be by extending OKHttp

Comment: @Nidheesh could you resolve problem? i have same problem