# Android AsyncTask onProgressUpdate - How to get progress percentage of an uploading file?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm using an Async task and using onProgressUpdate for uploading an image. It is running fine, but I'm facing problem in getting the percentage of file that is being uploaded.How can I get to know how much percentage of the file is currently uploaded. 
Below is the code I have used.

```
private class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground( String... params ) {


            String result = "";


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost( "http://192.168.212.177:8089/services/imageUpload" );

            try {
                Date todaysdate = new Date();
                for ( String imageFile : params ) {
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
                    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    FileBody bin = new FileBody( file );

                    MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

                    int strIndex = imageFile.lastIndexOf( "/" );
                    String imageName = imageFile.substring( strIndex + 1 , imageFile.length() );

                    multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart( "imageFile" , new StringBody(encodedImage , ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN ) );
                    multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart( "filename" , new StringBody( farmersEnteredNumber + "_" + datemill.getTime() , ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN ) );
                    multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart( "imageName" , new StringBody( imageName, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN ) );


                    long total = 0;

                    long lenghtOfFile = multiPartEntityBuilder.build().getContentLength();
                    publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    httpPostRequest.setEntity( multiPartEntityBuilder.build() );


                    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPostRequest );


                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    if ( inputStream != null )
                        result = convertInputStreamToString( inputStream );
                    else
                        result = "Did not work!";
                    return result;
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {

                return null;
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            FarmerDetails.this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog( FarmerDetails.this );
                    mProgressDialog.setTitle( "Image Uploading" );
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage( "Uploading Image Please Wait" );
                    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate( false );
                    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    mProgressDialog.show();

                }
            } );



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String result ) {
            super.onPostExecute( result );
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    }
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use count_of_uploaded_files\count_of_all_files as percentage.

Comment: And there is no need to use runOnUiThread() at onPreExecute() method of asyncTask. OnPreExecute is garantied to be called on UI thread

Comment: I'm trying to upload only one image...

Comment: Maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3246050/2893307   You can subclass HttpEntity to count of transmitted bytes.  Also, from which thread do you start this AsyncTask ?

Comment: Thanks Will have a look :) I started AsyncTask From the Main Thread