# HttpClient upload big file and show sent bytes number

Tags: java, http

I have found this code sample

```
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class PostFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9001/upload.php");
    File file = new File("c:/TRASH/zaba_1.jpg");

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);


    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
}
```

I am just wondering how to get uploaded bytes sum?

Comment: Are you looking for this size of the `File`, or the size of the entire POST (which will only be a little bit bigger)?

Comment: No, I am looking to get how many bytes were uploaded. To show the number in console

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload with Java (with progress bar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254719/file-upload-with-java-with-progress-bar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `FileBody.writeTo(OutputStream)` to counts bytes as they are written. This allows a count of bytes sent (even if interrupted), both during the upload and after it is complete.

```
public class FileBodyCounter extends FileBody {
    private volatile long byteCount;

    public long getBytesWritten() {
        return byteCount;
    }

    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) {
        super.writeTo(new FilterOutputStream(out) {
            // Other write() methods omitted for brevity. Implement for better performance
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                byteCount++;
                super.write(b);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use that instead of the standard `FileBody`, and retrieve the bytecount during upload, or after the post has completed.

Comment: I want to see the uploading process numbers. I mean not after but within :)

Comment: As stated above, you can access the bytes written count during the upload. Simply allow the upload to proceed on one thread, and call the `FileBodyCounter`'s `getBytesWritten()` method on another thread.

Comment: Thanks I will, but I was interested in MultiPartEntity to get the upload progress. I have found many examples :)