# How to do a progress bar to show progress download of a big file with AndroidAnnotations?

Tags: android, download, progress, android-annotations

I have an Android App and I want to download a big file.

REST API implementation is made with AndroidAnnotations. I need to show a progressbar with the download of a big file using this REST Client (made by AndroidAnnotations).

How I to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Its to late for answering this question but this will be helpful who are still finding ans with Android-annotation

You can check your image progress by little bit manipulation of code and here is what i have created my

**Custom converter Class:-**

```
public class CustomConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {

OnProgressListener mOnProgressListener;

public CustomConverter() {
    super();

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> partConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    partConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
    partConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
    partConverters.add(new ProgressResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    setPartConverters(partConverters);
}
```

//    public ProgressFormHttpMessageConverter setOnProgressListener(OnProgressListener listener) {
//        mOnProgressListener = listener;
//        return this;
//    }

```
class ProgressResourceHttpMessageConverter extends ResourceHttpMessageConverter {

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Resource resource, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = outputMessage.getBody();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        long contentLength = resource.contentLength();
        int byteCount = 0;
        int bytesRead = -1;
        Log.d("<3 <3 <3", "called");
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            byteCount += bytesRead;
            Log.d("<3 <3 <3 ** ", "progress" + String.valueOf((byteCount * 100) / contentLength));
            if(mOnProgressListener != null) {
                mOnProgressListener.onProgress(resource, byteCount, (int) contentLength);
            }
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}

public interface OnProgressListener {
    void onProgress(Resource resource, int downloaded, int downloadSize);
}
}
```

--> you can check your progress with log :)

**`Code Usage`**

-> Your rest class will be as follow:-

```
@Rest(rootUrl = CommonUtils.BASE_URL, converters = {ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class,
    CustomConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class})

public interface CustomRest extends RestClientErrorHandling {


@Post(pUrlSignUp)
String _SignUp(MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you will have to use `AsyncTask` for downloading purpose:

You can use its methods `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` for showing and dismissing the `ProgressDialog` respectively.

**Example:**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Activity activity;  //pass your activity reference while initialize this.

    public DownloadTask (Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        //download file's code here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is about AndroidAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> > use AsyncTask method "on progressupdate " to show progress
> ```

```
public class download extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

}
}

Comment: Sorry, but my question is about AndroidAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

With AndroidAnnotations, you can use background threads and [publishing progress](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Publish%20Progress) easily:

```
@EActivity
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle)
    doSomeStuffInBackground();
  }

  @Background
  void doSomeStuffInBackground() { // will run on a background thread
    publishProgress(0);
    // Do some stuff
    publishProgress(10);
    // Do some stuff
    publishProgress(100);
  }

  @UiThread
  void publishProgress(int progress) { // will run on the UI thread
    // Update progress views
  }

}
```

Now you can only have to figure out how you can get progress events. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412773/spring-for-android-file-upload-progress) can give a great inspiration. Unfortunetaly AFAIK there is no built-in callback for that in Spring Android Rest Template.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to solve this same problem, its being two months now. Finally found a good example, I cant believe everybody copy paste the same in AndroidAnnotations docs, if that were enough, we wouldnt be here seeking for help.

[Here is the link where you can see the example](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/154851/)

I made some modifications my self, for the moment its working with some toasts, but I hope to comeback with an actual loading animation to share:

```
    /*This background handles my main thread in UI and the progress publish*/
        @Background
        void thisGETJSON() {
            publishProgress(0);
            publishProgress(50);
            publishProgress(100);
            showJSONInUI();
        }

     /*Here the progress is published and the main UI thread is also called*/
        @UiThread
        void publishProgress(int progress) {

            if (progress == 0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Just a sec please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else if (progress == 50) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else if (progress == 100) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for waiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

      /*This is the main UI thread here I do cool stuff with the JSON objects*/
       @UiThread
       Void showJSONInUI(); {
       //Here I do something with the objects in the JSON
       }
```