# Help to find ConsoleConstants

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I just find the snippet which contains this code:

```
setHeaderEncoding(ConsoleConstants.UTF8_ENCODING)
```

But I just have file not found exception. So my question is where to find the lib which contains ConsoleConstants?

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Andrew

Comment: Isn't the class defined in the import? If you are using eclipse you should be able to do "ctrl+click" on the it to see its definition.

Comment: finding the complete package name will help track down where the file is from. Look for import something.somethingelse.ConsoleConstants; at the top of the file.

Comment: I don't know but I cannot import it because I don't have the lib installed or something :( I thought it should be in org.apache.commons.fileupload but I was wrong it is not from there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be referring to this SO answer: [File Upload with Java (with progress bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254719/file-upload-with-java-with-progress-bar/255079#255079)

The snippet appears to be using Apache Commons FileUpload, and calling [this method](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#setHeaderEncoding%28java.lang.String%29).  From the context, it would appear that is just wants the standard Java character encoding name for UTF-8; i.e. "UTF-8".

It is impossible to figure out which `ConsoleConstants` class the code is actually referring to, but it doesn't matter, IMO.  Just use a literal string.

Comment: So it can be replaced with just a const. ? It is like "UTF-8" etc ?

Comment: That's what the answer said... '...the standard Java character encoding name for UTF-8; i.e. "UTF-8".'  You should upvote the answer and then accept it (click the check mark).  Then go back and accept some answers to your other questions.