# How to implement file upload progress bar in android

Tags: android

I am uploading files via `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` in android and I need implement progress bar. Is it possible to grab progress from: ?

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("some path");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
File file = new File("file path");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
byte[] bArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
in.read(bArray);
String entity = Base64.encodeToString(bArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(entity));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
```

If not, please show an alternative way. Thanks

Comment: This post may be what your are looking for : [Java FileUpload with progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254719/file-upload-with-java-with-progress-bar) .

Answer (score 22):

What you're going to want to do is create an `AsyncTask` that can handle this for you, overriding the onProgressUpdate method.

Here's a stripped down version of a something I tested in another app using `HttpURLConnection`. There may be some small redundancies and I think `HttpURLConnection` may be generally frowned upon, but this should work. Just use this class in whatever Activity class you're using (in this example, I refer to it as `TheActivity`) by calling `new FileUploadTask().execute()`. Of course you may need to tweak this to fit the needs of your app.

```
private class FileUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(TheActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        try {
            File file = new File("file path");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream.read(bytes);
            fileInputStream.close();

            URL url = new URL("some path");
            HttpURLConnection connection = 
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

            int bufferLength = 1024;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += bufferLength) {
                int progress = (int)((i / (float) bytes.length) * 100);
                publishProgress(progress);
                if (bytes.length - i >= bufferLength) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, i, bufferLength);
                } else {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, i, bytes.length - i);
                }
            }
            publishProgress(100);

            outputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            // read the response
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't efficient as it progresses smoothly till 100 and then stuck on a 100 % after that dialog get dismiss when actually the file gets transfered. so there something missing in above code ?

Comment: The actual upload will be start when you flush the outputStream.
so the progress is a fake progress

Comment: Using `HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` uploads contents without buffering (see @Songlin answer).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think HttpURLConnection simply does the trick, as @Basbous pointed out, the actual data is bufferred until  outputStream.flush() is called. According to android [issue 3164](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3164), it's now fixed in  post-froyo platform (android 2.2, sdk version 8), you need use - java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode to work around the buffer behavior.