# How to read Json from online instead of asset folder

Tags: java, android, json

I was learning to make quiz app from online and it is going well. I was wondering instead of reading json from assets , it will be wise to read from online such that question can be added or changes accordingly and user don't have to update app.

Here is the JSON Structure.

```html
{"questions" : [{"category":"general","question": "Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's", "choices": ["largest railway station","highest railway station","longest railway station","None of the above"], "correctAnswer":0},
    {"category":"science","question": "Entomology is the science that studies", "choices": ["Behavior of human beings","Insects","The origin and history of technical and scientific terms","the formation of rocks"], "correctAnswer":1},

    {"category":"science", "question":"What is known as the 'master gland' of the human body?", "choices":["Thyroid gland","Pituitary gland","Pineal gland","Pancreas"],"correctAnswer":1}
  ]}
```

and the code to read from assets is

```html
    private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open("questionsJSON.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

I would like to show progress loading dialog when next question loads and any help will be largely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downloading json text content should be no different to downloading any other text context - what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Best option will be using [REST APIs](https://restfulapi.net/), Get data from Server/Database, which can be edited anytime from anywhere

You can learn to use [Node js](https://nodejs.org/), it is not hard and it is based on JavaScript.

For getting JSON from APIs you can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Learning and implementing these things will be a bit hard if you are beginner but it will be the best option for long run

hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using two different threads (or Runnables), one thread for downloading the JSON content and the other thread for displaying the GUI. For example, take a look at this: [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22273319/11666877)

The solution involved making a Runnable that would first start downloading the data from the online website and then update the current progress onto the GUI thread as it is downloading. He uses the [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) class so he can use a while loop to read the data in, update the number of bytes downloaded, get the current progress, and then display the results. I suppose you can do something similar here by using a while loop, and then checking if the download is finished. If so, you can close the display.