# When downloading a file from a URL, why do we read into a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, http, url, inputstream

Why do we read into a byte array when downloading a file from a URL? In the below code a byte array ('data') is created which is allocated a number of "1024" and is passed as a parameter in the below piece of code

```
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0)
```

Can you please explain what "reading" into a byte array means? Also, why were "0" and "1024" passed in as well?

This code was taken from [Java getting download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273045/java-getting-download-progress)

```
URL url = new URL("http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bitcoin/Bitcoin/blockchain/bitcoin_blockchain_170000.zip");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
long completeFileSize = httpConnection.getContentLength();

java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(httpConnection.getInputStream());
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(
        "package.zip");
java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(
        fos, 1024);
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

long downloadedFileSize = 0;
int x = 0;
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    downloadedFileSize += x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please explain what "reading" into a byte array means?

When we read data into a byte array, we mean that we store the data from an input stream into an array for later use. We read the data into a byte array instead of a char array or an int array because it is binary data. It might be text or a picture or a video. At the end of the day, these are all binary data that we store in bytes.

> Also, why were "0" and "1024" passed in as well?

[The documentation for `read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) says it takes 3 arguments:

> b - destination buffer.
>
> off - offset at which to start storing bytes.
>
> len - maximum number of bytes to read.

So the `0` is the "offset" where the read operation will start storing bytes. The `1024` is the number of bytes to read. These can be any sensible numbers as long as you don't try to read into a location past the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice ! Question, what if the resource (I.e. video) you are downloading is greater than the number of bytes you assigned to read (1024)? Won't an exception be thrown saying a greater byte array is needed?

Comment: @ZishanAmin No, no exception will be thrown in that case. This is why there is a `while` loop. It reads a 1 kilobyte block at a time.