# Http post request progress reporting

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to create a Java server and client such that the client sends a post request to the server, and the server does a lot of processing (~ 5 minutes) and then returns a file.

My problem is that I would like some kind of progress reporting during the long processing.  Is there any way to do this?

I figure I could send the progress information, and then when I am ready to send the file, send some delimiter and then the file, and the client could act appropriately, but I was wondering if there is a standard way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057342/how-to-get-a-progress-bar-for-a-file-upload-with-apache-httpclient-4

Comment: not quite.  in this case, I don't know the size of the file, and I can't start sending the file until the processing is done.