# clj-http: tracking progress of a multi-part file upload

Tags: clojure, multipart, clj-http

I am doing a multi-part file upload using [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http). I am wondering if there is a way I can track the progress of a file upload. Perhaps, some function that gets called periodically with how much of the file has been uploaded so far?

Answer (score 2):

clj-http uses Apache HTTP Client underneath so you can reuse a solution presented in [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057342/how-to-get-a-progress-bar-for-a-file-upload-with-apache-httpclient-4). However, it cannot be easily.

The code presented in the linked answer provides an enhanced implementation of `HttpEntity`. clj-http currently [doesn't support providing your own instance of `HttpEntity` as your request body](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/client.clj#L450).

You have two options:

1. Provide a pull request to clj-http so it supports providing an instance of `HttpEntity` as the `:body` value (e.g. by adding another `cond` branch checking for `HttpEntity` value or by making `wrap-input-coercion` a multimethod so you can extend it for `HttpEntity`).
2. Provide similar logic to that from the mentioned `FileEntity` and `OutputStreamProgress` but in your implementation of `org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody`. clj-http supports providing them as values for multipart attachments. The drawback here is that it would track progress per attachment, not per the whole request.