# How to upload file with progress percentage using JSoup library

Tags: java, file-upload, jsoup

I am using Jsoup 1.9. I want to upload a file to a PHP server. It must show a progress bar.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .data("file", file.getName(), new FileInputStream(file))
    .post();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Jsoup does not contain any UI components.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup 1.9.2 doesn't seem to provide this kind of feature (file upload progress monitoring).

However, you can either use **ApacheHttpClient** or use directly **java.net.URL**.
Here are two links explaining how to use one or other option:

- [How to get a progress bar for a file upload with Apache HttpClient 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057342/how-to-get-a-progress-bar-for-a-file-upload-with-apache-httpclient-4)
- [Upload a file using HTTPUrlConnection](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4090)