# MultipartEntity POST android

Tags: android, file-upload, multipartentity

I'm implementing app upload file by android.I have a service : http://example.com:1001/UPLOAD/FileUpload.do. I want to upload a file and two parameter like that

0?event=Upload&type=:1

:0 SERVER [current http://example.com:1001/UPLOAD/FileUpload.do]

:1 {invoice, signature}

:2 File on form with name: UploadedFile

When I copy and paste : http://example.com:1001/UPLOAD/FileUpload.do on browser then it response a form like that

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="FileUpload.do" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="UploadedFile"></input>
        <input type="hidden" value="invoice" name="type"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="event_Upload"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my code android:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();           
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com:1001/UPLOAD/FileUpload.do");
File file = new File(pathFile);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("event", new StringBody("Upload"));
reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("invoice"));
reqEntity.addPart("UploadedFile", fileBody);

httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);              
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

But I don't know , why it doesn't upload to server . What's wrong???

Answer (score 1):

The `<form>` says `event_Upload`; you have just `event`. Does that help?

See also [Upload a file through an HTTP form, via MultipartEntityBuilder, with a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964288/upload-a-file-through-an-http-form-via-multipartentitybuilder-with-a-progress)

Comment: I have already replace event by event_Upload, but It doesn't work , terrible for me :(