# How to get the text from a addTextBody in a miltipartentitybuilder

Tags: java, android

so the new way to work with multipartentity is with multipartentitybuilder. I looked on stackoverflow and it seems one of the accepted ways to use that is with this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188010 However, and this may be a dumb question, but in that example, how do I actually get the username and password from the request at server side?

Thanks for the time!