# How to get the text from addTextBody in a MultipartEntityBuilder?

Tags: java, servlets, multipartentity

I am using an Android client to post data and some file in Google cloud storage:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
             entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); 
             entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file);             
             entityBuilder.addTextBody("author", author);
```

On the server side I am using a servlet to get that request.
However, while I am able to get the file and store it, I don't know how to get what's in the addTextBody (the "author" String in my case)

I have been searching for a while and just found someone that posted quite the same question but no one answered him. ([How to get the text from a addTextBody in a miltipartentitybuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232372/how-to-get-the-text-from-a-addtextbody-in-a-miltipartentitybuilder))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Servlet 3.0+, just use [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29). For example, if you wanted the content of the multipart part named `author`, you'd configure your servlet with `@MultipartConfig`, retrieve the appropriate `Part` object and consume its `InputStream`.

```
@MultipartConfig()
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/upload" })
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Collection<Part> parts = req.getParts();
        for (Part part : parts) {
            if (!part.getName().equals("author"))
                continue;
            try (InputStream in = part.getInputStream()){
                String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(in));
                System.out.println(content); // prints the value of author
            }
        }
    }
}
```