# How to get progress in Http post Android?

Tags: android, http, http-post

Is there a way to get progress data, to display ProgressBar(Horizontal), using DefaultHttpClient with image encoded to Base64 in params. I am also sending some other params. Similar thing is achieved in iOS .Is there any workout for Android.

**EDIT**

```
HttpRequestBase request;
if(mode == MODE.POST)
  request = new HttpPost(((Context) mWeakreReference.get()).getString(R.string.base_url)+ url);

 request.setHeader(UrlService.HEADER_API_CONTENT_TYPE_KEY, UrlService.HEADER_API_CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE);
 request.setHeader(UrlService.HEADER_DEVICE_ID, Utility.getDeviceId(mWeakreReference.get()));
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Image and data is posted neatly . I have to display progress bar how can I achieve that.

Comment: add more details and also image

Comment: You cannot do it using this...try use multipart..

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but after spending some time looking for an answer online, I built my own tiny library:
https://github.com/licryle/HTTPPoster

It's based of an [StockOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964288/upload-a-file-through-an-http-form-via-multipartentitybuilder-with-a-progress), and another [article](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) found online.

The former uses deprecated Classes, and the latter doesn't show the Entities. It wraps the whole in an ASync task.

To use:

1. Download & extract
2. In your build.gradle Module file, add the dependency:

```
dependencies 
{    
     compile project(':libs:HTTPPoster') 
}
```

3. You need a class to implement the `HttpListener` interface so you can listen to the callbacks. It has four callbacks in `HTTPListener`:

   - onStartTransfer
   - onProgress
   - onFailure
   - onResponse
4. Configure the ASyncTask & start it. Here's a quick usage:

```
HashMap<String, String> mArgs = new HashMap<>();
mArgs.put("lat", "40.712784");
mArgs.put("lon", "-74.005941");

ArrayList<File> aFileList = getMyImageFiles();

HttpConfiguration mConf = new HttpConfiguration(
    "http://example.org/HttpPostEndPoint",
    mArgs,
    aFileList,
    this, // If this class implements HttpListener
    null,  // Boundary for Entities - Optional
    15000  // Timeout in ms for the connection operation
    10000, // Timeout in ms for the reading operation
);

new HttpPoster().execute(mConf);
```

hope that can help :) Feel also free to suggest improvements! It's very recent, and I extend it as I need it

Cheers